Хранение NULL в таблице SQL Server
На SQL Server есть таблица, в которой в числе прочих столбцов имеется столбец типа bit, не допускающий NULL. Появилась потребность сделать его nullable, но есть опасение: не приведет ли это к увеличению размера таблицы? Вопрос такой: как именно SQL Server хранит значения NULL? В частности, если дело касается NULL в столбце типа bit. Заранее благодарен :)

NULL bitmap присутствует в структуре всегда и не зависит от свойства nullability и/или наличия NULL в значении.

Там может быть другая проблема - что само преобразование таблицы будет долго идти. Я вот только не помню это когда добавляешь nullable или когда убираешь такая проблема была. Если записей очень много, то имейте в виду, что может быть такая засада. Я в своё время так и не понял как с этим бороться, разве что новый столбец создавать. Старый столбец переделывался на новый тип какое-то нереальное время, если были миллионы записей в таблице. Хотя может у меня это с каким-то другим типом данных было и полей было много, может у вас такого и не будет.

@CrazyElf А модифицируемая таблица случайно не создавалась как sparse?

@Akina Да это было лет 7 назад и несколько работ назад, поэтому я уж и не помню/не знаю. Помню, что гуглил тогда и понял, что проблема реально имеет место быть. Может с тех пор что-то в движке БД уже поменяли. Помню там в одну сторону быстро таблица переделывалась, а в другую никак. Но в какую именно сторону - забыл. Может убрать хотели тогда nullable. Не помню.

Всем большое спасибо! Нет, не как sparse

NOT NULL -> NULL должно быстро пройти, вот наоборот может быть долго на больших таблицах, т.к. нужно проверять все существующие данные. К увеличению не приведёт.

Nullable-колонки в Sql Server рекомендуют размещать в конце. Тогда значения null вообще не будут занимать место. Но это такой микро-хак, что особо не стоит обращать на него внимания. Column order doesn’t matter… generally, but – IT DEPENDS!
